# Python on cmd path

Tags: python

How can I append python to path? I tried put the python root, .exe, libs folder, but nothin work. I just want run .py files at cmd in windows.

Thanks.

Comment: What env variable are you modifying? classpath is a java thing. For commands, cmd looks at PATH.

Comment: You do in fact need to add python to your path. However, that won't magically allow you to run .py files by calling them. You'll need to run them like `python path/to/file.py`

Answer (score 4):

Control Panel, System, Advanced tab, Environment Variables (Windows XP).  Edit PATH:

```
PATH=C:\Python26;C:\Windows;.... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the PATH where the python interpreter has visibility is available from `sys.path`

```
>>>import sys
>>>print sys.path
```

If you want to new paths to be added that list, just append to it.

```
>>>sys.path.append('c:/new/path/to/lib')
```

Comment: >>>print (sys.path) could be the new format??
I am just starting and that is what is working.

Answer (score 0):

cmd has **environment variables**, commands that are recognized.

To add the **python** command to cmd, you have to add the path to the folder in the **control panel's** *environment variables* section, which calls the **python.exe** file in your PC's Python folder.

To do this,

1. Type: **environment variables** in the search bar
2. Press the environment variables button
   [image]
3. Edit **PATH** variable
   [image]
4. Add path to **PATH** variable
   [image]
   It varies for where you installed python, but for me it is at:

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32

To find the **python.exe** file

The AppData folder might be invisible. If the case, the following website is a good reference on making invisible folders visible https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/

5. Apply changes and open a new cmd window.

For the **pip** command, the same steps apply, only that the **pip.exe** file is in the \Scripts folder.